# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clone' in Peewee with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, peewee

I am trying to get the following query:

```
ignored = Activity.select().join(StuActIgnore).join(Student).where(Student.id == current_user.id)
Activity.select().where(~(Activity.name**"%BBP") & Activity not in ignored)
```

This does not give me any errors, but any of the following:

```
Activity.get(~(Activity.name**"%BBP") & Activity not in ignored)
Activity.select().where(~(Activity.name**"%BBP") & Activity not in ignored).join(Course)
```

gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

If I try this:

```
Activity.select().join(Course).join(StuCouRel).join(Student).where(~(Activity.name**"%BBP") & Activity not in ignored & Student.id == current_user.id)
```

it will tell me that:

```
    TypeError: argument of type 'Expression' is not iterable
```

I find this very confusing, because this:

```
already_selected = Course.select().join(StuCouRel).join(Student).where(Student.id == current_user.id)
to_choose = Course.select().where(Course not in already_selected)
```

works perfectly fine, while it is very analogous to what I'm trying to do, it seems.

I have absolutely no idea what this might mean and I can't find anything in the documentation. 'bool' object probably stands for boolean, but I cannot see how the result of my query is a boolean. I also don't know what 'clone' means and I also don't know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python casts whatever `__contains__()` returns to a boolean.  That is why you cannot use "not in" or "in" when constructing peewee queries.  You instead use `<<` to signify "IN".

You might try:

```
ignored = (Activity
           .select()
           .join(StuActIgnore)
           .join(Student)
           .where(Student.id == current_user.id))
Activity.select().where(~(Activity.name**"%BBP") & ~(Activity.id << ignored))
```

See the docs on querying for more info http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#column-lookups

Comment: Also there's a gotcha I tend to hit every now and then; forgetting to provide the model attribute in equivalency check.. i.e. doing Account.get(name==name) instead of Account.get(Account.name==name). 

The first piece of code ends up querying "..FROM "account" AS t1 WHERE ? [True]" and it fails here https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/2.6.1/peewee.py#L2252 with
"AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clone'"

It'd be nice if it'd wrap the exception in a reminder of the syntax. :)

Comment: @stt care to make that an answer?